# Publishing QGIS Projects with QWC2

Tags: qgis-web-client

I want to publish my own QGIS-Projects with QWC2 on web. Every time I generate my service configuration at QWC-admin I get this result:

```
INFO: Config destination: '/srv/qwc_service/config-out/default'
INFO: Searching for projects files in /srv/qwc_service/config-in/default/qgis_projects
INFO: Processing /srv/qwc_service/config-in/default/qgis_projects/test.qgs
INFO: Written to /data/gen/test.qgs
INFO: Searching for projects files in /data/scan
INFO: Scanning for thumbnail(test.png) under /qwc2/assets/img/mapthumbs
INFO: Thumbnail: test.png could not be found under /qwc2/assets/img/mapthumbs/test.png
INFO: Adding project /data/scan/test.qgs
INFO: Scanning for thumbnail(natural-earth-countries.png) under /qwc2/assets/img/mapthumbs
INFO: Thumbnail: natural-earth-countries.png could not be found under /qwc2/assets/img/mapthumbs/natural-earth-countries.png
INFO: Adding project /data/scan/natural-earth-countries.qgs
INFO: Downloading GetProjectSettings from http://qwc-qgis-server/ows/qwc_demo
INFO: Downloading GetProjectSettings from http://qwc-qgis-server/ows/scan/test
CRITICAL: Could not get GetProjectSettings from http://qwc-qgis-server/ows/scan/test:
b'Layer(s) not valid\n'
INFO: Downloading GetProjectSettings from http://qwc-qgis-server/ows/scan/natural-earth-countries
INFO: Writing 'ogcConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Reading 'qwc_demo.qgs'
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_edit_lines.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_edit_points.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_edit_polygons.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_countries.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_country_names.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_states_provinces.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_geographic_lines.ui
INFO: Using WMS GetMap to generate thumbnail for qwc_demo
WARNING: Skipping theme item '': Could not get capabilities for /ows/scan/test
INFO: Using WMS GetMap to generate thumbnail for scan/natural-earth-countries
INFO: Copying 'index.html' to tenant dir
INFO: Skipping JSON schema check for MapViewer
INFO: Writing 'mapViewerConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'featureInfoConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'printConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'searchConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'adminGuiConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'dbAuthConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'elevationConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'mapinfoConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'permalinkConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Reading 'qwc_demo.qgs'
INFO: Writing 'dataConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'legendConfig.json' service config file
CRITICAL: The generation of the configuration files resulted in a failure
CRITICAL: The configuration files were not updated!
INFO: Collecting 'ogc' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'mapViewer' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'featureInfo' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'print' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'search' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'adminGui' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'dbAuth' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'elevation' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'mapinfo' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'permalink' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'data' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'legend' service permissions
INFO: Writing 'permissions.json' permissions file
CRITICAL: The generation of the permission files resulted in a failure.
CRITICAL: The permission files were not updated!
```

My layers are stored in a PostGIS Database but every time my Layers are not valid.
The destination folder of the example - project 'qwc-demo' is the "data" - folder, but my own projects are always stored in the data/scan or data/gen folder.
My test.qgs project has only one standard .shp layer.

How can I publish my own projects on with QWC2 easily?

Comment: The Web Server seems to be unable to access your data. Does your QWC2 server have access to your PostGIS DB? Best practice is setting up a service using pg_service.conf

Comment: @fabian96 Did you solve this issue? I can access the DB via QGIS and have tried with a layer in that but get this error. I am also not able to open the default natual-earth-countries.qgs as the db doesn't work with the passwords in the qwc documentation

Comment: @GeorgeC yes I solved this problem. You have to save your projects in the scan - folder and NOT in the qgs-resources folder! Therefore you have to rename the qgs-resources folder so there is guaranteed no access.

Comment: @fabian96. The scan folder is within the qgs-resources folder. In qwc-services.github.io/setup/quick-start a different folder is suggested that's different from the github notes. Were you able to access the postgres DB when you opened the default qgs file in QGIS? and where did you put your gpkg data?